# url argument error in my code for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, safari

I borrowed and tweaked this code from another thread.

I have a button on the Google Sheets screen, which when clicked, creates a new UI window/screen with a clickable link, and the link is correctly referenced, but when you click that link it doesn't actually do anything.

The `URLValue` from AA1 would just be a concatenation of a Google Form address, with a code to pre fill the form with a number from my spreadsheet. The link all works as a cell content, and works fine from Chrome, but doesn't do anything in Safari.

```
function AddStock(){
  var URLValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA1').getValue();
  showAnchor('Add Stock',URLValue);
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of `URLValue` of `var URLValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA1').getValue();`?

Comment: The URLValue from AA1 would just be a concatenation of a google form address, with a code to pre fill the form with a number from my spreadsheet. The link all works as a cell content, and works fine from Chrome, but doesn't do anything in Safari.

Comment: This `<a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">` is kind of a bad thing to do because it set's up a race condition.  What if it closes the window before it goes to the url.  You would probably be better of to use withSuccessHandler to close the window thus allowing some time between the two actions.

Comment: Did you log URLValue to make sure it was getting the right format?

Comment: Yes, I added console.log(URLValue) and it prints perfectly in the console window. No idea why it won't actually open the page. Everything on it works fine. And it works perfectly in Chrome too, but not in Safari?? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get a console error when you click the link? Does it work without the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: I don't have a console error, it just doesn't do anything. When I try without the onclick, the link doesn't close the message window.